# How to update a listbox widget automatically when inserting or deleting entries?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter, listbox

In this program, I am trying to build a phonebook app. I am using database here. I created a listbox widget to display all my contacts. I also added a create and delete button and both are working fine.The only problem here is I always need to rerun my code to get the new contact added to appear in listbox. Same with delete as well. I want the program to update the contact list when I press save button or delete button so that the updated list appears in listbox widget.
how can I do that?
help

```
import contact_database
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

root = Tk()
root.title("Phone Book")
root.minsize(600,500)
root.maxsize(600,500)
root.iconbitmap("D:\Downloads\pic2.ico")






frame= LabelFrame(root,font=("Comic Sans MS",10,"bold"))
frame.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=60,pady=90)


f_name  = Label(root,text=",First name",font=("Helvetica",13,"bold")).place(x=110,y=50)
l_name  = Label(root,text="Last name",font=("Helvetica",13,"bold")).place(x=15,y=50)
phone  = Label(root,text="Phone number",font=("Helvetica",13,"bold")).place(x=300,y=50)



conatact_list = Listbox(root,font=("Comic Sans MS",15,"bold"),width=60,height=14,selectmode=SINGLE)
conatact_list.place(x=10,y=100)

    
conn = sqlite3.connect("contcts.db")

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT rowid, *FROM contact_list")
items=c.fetchall()

for item in items:

    conatact_list.insert(END, str(item[0])+ ">>"+item[2]+","+item[1]+"-------->"+item[3])



conn.commit()
conn.close()


def delete():
    a_contact = conatact_list.get(ANCHOR)   
    para_list  = (a_contact.split('>'))
    r_id = para_list[0]
    contact_database.delete_one(r_id)




def create_new():
        top = Toplevel()
        top.minsize(610,220)
        top.maxsize(610,220)
        top.title("Add new contacts-")

        f_name = Entry(top,font=("Helvetica",15),width=15,borderwidth=0,bg="black",fg="white")
        f_name.place(x=30,y=40)
        l_name = Entry(top,font=("Helvetica",15),width=15,borderwidth=0,bg="black",fg="white")
        l_name.place(x=220,y=40)
        phone = Entry(top,font=("Helvetica",15),width=15,borderwidth=0,bg="black",fg="white")
        phone.place(x=410,y=40)

        f_label = Label(top,text="Enter first name",font=("Helvetica",10,"bold")).place(x=60,y=80)
        l_label = Label(top,text="Enter last name",font=("Helvetica",10,"bold")).place(x=250,y=80)
        ph_label = Label(top,text = "Enter phone number",font=("Helvetica",10,"bold")).place(x=430,y=80)

        confirm_label = Label(top,font=("Comic Sans MS",10,"bold"),fg="red")
        confirm_label.place(y=10,x=180)

        def save():
            
            contact_database.add_one(f_name.get(),l_name.get(),phone.get())
            confirm_label.config(text="CONTACT SAVED SUCCESSFULLY !")

           
            
                                
            
        



        def clr():
            f_name.delete(0,END)
            l_name.delete(0,END)
            phone.delete(0,END)
            confirm_label.config(text="")

        save_button = Button(top,text="SAVE",font=("Helvetica",10,"bold"),bg="lightgreen",command=save).place(x=260,y=130)
        clear_button = Button(top,text="CLEAR",font=("Helvetica",10,"bold"),bg="yellow",command=clr).place(x=257,y=170)

def delete():
    a_contact = conatact_list.get(ANCHOR)   
    para_list  = (a_contact.split('>'))
    r_id = para_list[0]
    contact_database.delete_one(r_id)

    

    


add = Button(root,text="Add new contact +",font=("Helvetica",10,"bold"),command=create_new,bg="skyblue").place(x=10,y=10)
delete = Button(root,text="Delete selected ",font=("Helvetica",10,"bold"),command=delete,bg="red").place(x=470,y=10)


root.mainloop()


----------
```

Comment: When you save the changes in the database, call the function that connects to the database and gets the values

Comment: I tried that, but in that case, a new window is created every time I press the save button. I don't want that. I want a single-window with updated listbox

Comment: I am  telling move **only** the code that updates the listbox to a separate function

Answer (score 0):

First move the below code:

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect("contcts.db")

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT rowid, *FROM contact_list")
items=c.fetchall()

for item in items:

    conatact_list.insert(END, str(item[0])+ ">>"+item[2]+","+item[1]+"-------->"+item[3])



conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

into a function as below:

```py
def update_contact_list():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("contcts.db")
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("SELECT rowid, * FROM contact_list")
    items = c.fetchall()

    conatact_list.delete(0, END) # clear current list
    for item in items:
        conatact_list.insert(END, str(item[0])+ ">>"+item[2]+","+item[1]+"-------->"+item[3])

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

# need to call once to show the current contact list
update_contact_list()
```

Then you can call the function after deleting record:

```py
def delete():
    a_contact = conatact_list.get(ANCHOR)
    para_list  = (a_contact.split('>'))
    r_id = para_list[0]
    contact_database.delete_one(r_id)
    # refresh contact list
    update_contact_list()
    # or simply call 'conatact_list.delete(ANCHOR)'
```

and after adding record:

```py
def save():

    contact_database.add_one(f_name.get(),l_name.get(),phone.get())
    confirm_label.config(text="CONTACT SAVED SUCCESSFULLY !")
    # refresh contact list
    update_contact_list()
    # if .add_one(...) can return the new "rowid"
    # you can call 'conatact_list.insert(END, f"{rowid}>>{l_name.get()},{f_name.get()}-------->{phone.get()}")
```

*Note that your posted code has duplicate `delete()` functions.*

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. It worked for me. I was trying to find a solution for whole day.

Comment: @AnimeshSingh If it works for you, you are appreciated to accept it as the answer.